# C++: Why is the sum 0 in this for loop?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ with a book and one question was:

*What does the following for loop do? What is the final value of sum?*

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = -100; i <= 100; ++i)
  sum += i;
```

To know what the final value of sum is, I put in the code in my editor, with everything else it needs to work (main and header) and the only result I was getting was 0.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = -100; i <= 100; ++i)
    sum += i;
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

There are no error messages. Just the value of sum is 0 in that piece of code.
If I write the same code but replacing -100 with a positive 100 I get "100" as the value of sum.

Can someone explain, why it is 0?

Comment: Because it's sum += i, so sum==0, then sum+=-100, sum==-100 then sum+=-99, sum == -199.. and so on. On the last iteration of the loop sum==-99 then sum+=99 ==0

Comment: @freakish It is basic math but it may not be as intuitive to someone who doesn't know the program language or understand loop iterations very well..

Comment: @freakish yeah, I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @Nina _"or understand loop iterations "_ Well, even that't pretty basic math to tell what's the range of natural numbers between -100 and +100 including the borders will be, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a simpler but equivalent example:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = -2; i <= 2; ++i)
  sum += i;
```

You should be able to see it is equivalent to:

```
sum += -2;
sum += -1;
sum += 0;
sum += 1;
sum += 2;
```

And clearly the final sum is zero.

Incidentally, an optimizing compiler can understand that entire operation and realize the final sum is zero, and therefore the loop doesn't actually need to run at all, it can be skipped entirely and take zero CPU time.  Pretty cool: https://godbolt.org/z/dfs83TT4E

Comment: Interesting note about the compiler optimisation.

Comment: It is almost comical what gets compiled out. Routinely someone will drop a complex monstrosity of loops in a question and some weird profiling results. About as often as not the loop nightmare will turn out to have no observable result and be compiled down to less than a no-op. The rest of the time it turns out to be something like this where the compiler determines that the loop is a glorified constant or produces a very limited set of outputs and annihilates nearly all of the work. And these are far from stupid people asking these questions. The compiler's just damn smart.